# How to stop loading on interceptor.r axios.interceptors.request in ionic vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, axios

I am following this tutorial.

https://www.djamware.com/post/5fc19e3e77862f22905c7f03/ionic-5-tutorial-oauth2-login-example-vue

in this tutorial he is calling this function which calls on every axios request

```
mountRequestInterceptor() {
        this._requestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
            console.log("show loading");
            const loading = await loadingController.create({
                message: 'Please wait...'
            });
            await loading.present();
           
                
           
            
            return config;
        });
        console.log(this._requestInterceptor,'sasdas')
    },
```

Problem is loading starts on axios request but never stops.

I want it to stop when request is successfull

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the problem with your code, but I don't see where is `_interceptors.response`.

I made the same functionality to have a global loader.
I started it in `_interceptors.request` and turned it off in `_interceptors.response`.

maybe this blog will help you

https://codeburst.io/global-loader-component-using-vue-js-and-axios-interceptors-3880a136a4ac

Answer (score 0):

Yes I also have the same problem, how to fix it you just need to add a function to check whether the **loadingController** is still running or not.. the problem is why the loading doesn't want to stop because the function adds another **loadingController** when processing data,

You can add this function to check whether the **loadingController** is still running or not

```
const checkLoading = await loadingController.getTop();
```

So you can change the function to be like this,

```
mountRequestInterceptor() {
        this._requestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
            const checkLoading = await loadingController.getTop();
            if (!checkLoading) {
                console.log("show loading");
                const loading = await loadingController.create({
                    message: 'Please wait...'
                });
                await loading.present();
            }
            return config;
        });
    },
```